# What are some of the different interactions with empty remote servers in Android: Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

This is a multi-part question about empty remote servers. Each of these questions came up during gameplay and I'm hoping to get clarification on them since some of the interactions aren't completely clear.

1. What defines an empty remote server? If a remote server has ICE
   protecting it but no agenda/asset/whatever installed behind the ICE,
   is it still empty?
2. Is an empty remote server analogous to a new
   remote server? For an example of context, let's say when playing
   [Mushin No Shin](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05015).
3. Consider a remote server with no ICE that has an asset installed with an
   ability that has a cost of trashing the asset (say, like the remove from game ability on [Jackson
   Howard](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04015)). The runner runs on
   the server and in response the corp trashes the asset. Does the
   server still exist or is it simply an empty remote server? Is the
   run still successful?

Comment: Can you explain how the corp trashes the Jackson Howard in #3? I'm having trouble finding which rule allows that. http://netrunnerdb.com/en/rules

Comment: Since this paid ability doesn't require a click, it can be used just before the card is accessed, so long as it is rezzed. http://netrunnerdb.com/en/rules#rop107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A remote server requires **at least one piece of ICE protecting it** or **at least one card installed in the server itself** (i.e. agenda/asset/upgrade) to exist. The three central servers always exist. "**Empty**" would refer to a server with only ICE protecting it, and nothing in it.
2. Empty servers already exist so is different from a new server. Cards like Mushin No Shin, which specify a new server, **must interact with a new server** (i.e. that they create).
3. If a server ceases to exist during the run (e.g. as the result of a Jackson Howard removal that you describe), **the run immediately ends, and is considered neither successful nor unsuccessful**.

   The same is true if the trashed card is an ICE. For instance, if an empty server is defended only by a Data Mine which triggers, the server ceases to exist.

Comment: Interesting. So for the third question, triggers that need a successful or unsuccessful run will not apply, correct?

Comment: Exactly.  So, if you Dirty Laundry a naked Jackson Howard and the Corp uses his ability, you don't get the credits since it isn't successful.

Comment: The reference in the rules for #3 is http://netrunnerdb.com/en/rules#faq12, BUT I'm having trouble finding any justification in the rules for the Jackson Howard example in particular. A better example might be an empty server protected only by Paper Wall?

Comment: @AndrewVandever: On page 33 of the official rules, a run on a naked server immediately goes to step 4. Technically, the runner can decide to jack out, but if they're looking for a successful run that is unlikely. Then in step 4.1, cards can be rezzed and paid abilities can be triggered. Jackson's trash ability is a paid ability. When Jackson is trashed, this then causes the interaction that you are citing in the FAQ since the server is now destroyed.

Comment: In hindsight @AndrewVandever, that would actually make for a decent BG@SE question since run timings can become confusing.

Comment: Also, looks like the timing of a run was updated in the [FAQ](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/rules#tsr1). Step 4.1 in the core rules is now step 4.3 in the [FAQ](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/rules#tsr4_3).

Comment: @Ellesedil aha yeah, I see your point now. Boy, that is annoying! :)